# Thread doesn't start until application restarted on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, jsoup

I am trying to get html data from a website and for now am simply changing a textview to the title of the webpage. For some reason this textview only displays the title whenever I exit the application and reopen it. I am guessing this is due to the threading and something that I do not know about it. As an example, here is my code for the stackoverflow.com website:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get();
                titlestring = doc.title();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    downloadThread.start();

    TextView maintext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintext);

    Log.i("wbbug", "Title string: " + titlestring);
    maintext.setText(titlestring);

}
```

For some reason, it does not show the title of the webpage until I start the application, press home, then reopen it. Why is this?

Comment: check the activity lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextView maintext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintext);
 Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get();
                titlestring = doc.title();

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                     {
                       run(){
                    Log.i("wbbug", "Title string: " + titlestring);
                    maintext.setText(titlestring);
                            }
                     }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    };
    downloadThread.start();
```

Your `maintext.setText()` invokes before you get the title of your page but at the second time the `titlestring` is already initiated with your value and `setText` get your page name.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the webpage in a background thread(which is good), without waiting for the HTTP request to complete, you take `titlestring` and assume it contains the title of the webpage, but that will always not be the case.

Try this:

```
TextView maintext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maintext);
Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {                         
    public void run() {                                        
        Document doc;                                          
        try {                                              
            final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get();
            maintext.post(new Runnable(){
                maintext.setText(doc.title());
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {                       
            e.printStackTrace();                        
        }                                                       
    }                                                   
};                                                      
downloadThread.start();
```

Set text for the textview after you *get* the Document. Note `setText()` operates on UI component, so you have to do `maintext.setText()` in the UI thread, `View.post()` is one of a few ways of running code in UI thread.